# I can't input text into my form that is inside a jQuery UI accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Like the title says, I have a form with a single input and button inside of a jQuery UI Accordion content div and I can't type any text into it when I test it out. I can also not click the button.

Here is the HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="ic-open-report"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><p>Export Savings Report</p></buttOn>
                    <div id="ic-savings-report">
                        <h4>Export a PDF Savings Report</h4>
                            <div>
                            <form method="POST" class="savings-report">

                                        <input style="user-select: text;" type="email" id="ic-email"  placeholder="Email">
                                        <button type="submit" >Export</button>
                            </form>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$('#ic-savings-report').accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    animate: 400
});
$('#ic-savings-report').hide();

$('#ic-open-report').click(function(){
    $('#ic-savings-report').toggle(700);
    setTimeout("$( '#ic-savings-report' ).accordion( 'option', 'active', 0       );", 1000);
});
```

I'm not even sure why this would happen. Why would I be unable to edit the input?

Here is a link to the actual project: 
http://lcstuff.000webhostapp.com/intellifrost-calculator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this problem and jquery ui was setting the `font-size: 1em` on this element `.ui-widget input` and for some reason this made the text invisible. So it gave the impression that I couldn't input any text as no text was showing when I typed.

I just set it to the following to fix it:

```
font-size: 14px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work just fine as long as you reference JQuery and JQuery UI properly:

```js
$('#ic-savings-report').accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    animate: 400
});
$('#ic-savings-report').hide();

$('#ic-open-report').click(function () {
    $('#ic-savings-report').toggle(700);
    setTimeout("$( '#ic-savings-report' ).accordion( 'option', 'active', 0       );", 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="ic-open-report">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
    <p>Export Savings Report</p>
</button>
<div id="ic-savings-report">
    <h4>Export a PDF Savings Report</h4>
    <div>
        <form method="POST" class="savings-report">
    
            <input style="user-select: text;" type="email" id="ic-email" placeholder="Email">
            <button type="submit">Export</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work for me when I try your references. This is the link to the project: http://lcstuff.000webhostapp.com/intellifrost-calculator/ . The top button that says "export savings report" of the two green floating buttons is the one with the form.

Comment: I don't think your issue is with this code. I see the problem as the email field and button are layered behind the element with the text of *"Enter the values of your own refrigeration system to calculate how much IntellFrost could save you in defrost costs."*. You will need to hide that element to reveal the accordion behind it.

Comment: That's the joyride plugin I have going. If you just click the buttons on those they will go away. Even if I disable that script so that element never appears I still can't input anything into the text field

Comment: Again, the problem is not with this particular code that you are showing here. Because as I have shown you it works properly. The problem must be how this code is interacting with other code in your page.

Comment: I figured out the problem and it had to do with something else in the code. In the CSS. thanks